# Fetching GET API request parameter in server socket programming accepting HTTP request

Tags: java, sockets, http, get

How to fetch the timeout parameter in this GET Api request.

"api/request?connId=19&timeout=100"

I have to implement by building a socket server accepting HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0):

`request.getParameter("timeout")`

Comment: I am using servlet GET request. Its socket server programming. small highlight of my code. Socket clientSocket = server.accept();
            InputStreamReader isr =  new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());

Comment: I don't think request.getParameter("timeout") works here.